# How to pass config data to view component

Tags: javascript, node.js, vue.js, config

everyone. I've got a little node.js project with vue.js and I'd like to use a config packet (`npm i config`) in it. But when I add config to the `vue.js` component

```
import configData from config
```

and try to use one in the `vue.js` component

```
data: () => { config: configData }
```

I've got an exception when I make a request to the page. In the browser console appear:

```
Uncaught Error: Config file /config/runtime.json cannot be read. Error code is: undefined. Error message is: v.readFileSync is not a function
```

So I'd like to understand what's wrong with this config packet in `vue.js`. Is there a way to pass config data to the `Vue` component? Thanks a lot in advance

I created `/config/default.json` that contains the data I need, but when I try to pass it into my `vue.js` component the component page fall

Comment: did you try this: data: (config: configData ) => { 
someConfigUsage(config);
}

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a method that should return some variables. There is a mistake in your code. arrow functions works like this
if you want to return an empty object

```
data: () => ({})
```

If you want to call some method inside of it

```
func: () => {
    someMethod();
    anotherMethod();
}
```

And you can't write

```
data: () => { config: configData }
```

this is a mistake. You should put braces around your curly braces

Comment: Your answer was very helpful. I really made mistake when wrote this part, but unfortunately your excellent answer doesn't help on the merits of question.

Comment: You can try `Vue.use` method to add some configs. Call it in root component